# Cannot invoke 'contains' with an argument list of Type '([Foo], Foo)'

Tags: ios, swift

I'm attempting to use the `contains` function in swift to see if my objects is in a typed array but I'm getting:

> Cannot invoke 'contains' with an argument list of Type '([Foo], Foo)'

```
class Foo {

}

let foo = Foo()
let foos = [Foo(), Foo()]

contains(foos, foo)
```

Why is this happening?

## Update #1

I've implemented the `==` function but I still get the same error. Am I doing this improperly?

```
class Foo {}

func ==(lhs: Foo, rhs: Foo) -> Bool {
    return ObjectIdentifier(lhs) == ObjectIdentifier(rhs)
}

let foo = Foo()
let foos = [Foo(), Foo()]

contains(foos, foo)
```

Comment: You can't find a needle in a haystack unless you have a way of identifying a needle when you see it.

Comment: I guess I was expecting that `Foo` would inherit some kind of sensible default for determining equality like in other languages.

Comment: Inherit from what? You didn't give Foo a superclass, so what's to inherit? If you had derived it from NSObject, things would have been different...

Comment: Sorry, I'm coming from ruby where `class Foo; end` inherits from `Object`

Comment: I too often wish Swift were Ruby. But it isn't. It's sort of the opposite of Ruby! :(

Comment: You still didn't adopt Equatable. You're not really listening to what you're being told...

Comment: My apologies. As I stated I'm coming from ruby which is duck-typed (no need to adopt). I appreciate your help but you really should try to be more patient...

Comment: Time to call in the Foo Fighters!

Comment: I guess I felt that Rob Napier had handed you the whole answer on a plate. Also, it's probably unwise to use Swift without pausing to learn it (kind of like driving blindfolded), and I _have_ gone out of my way to write an extensive tutorial aimed at helping you: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_why_protocols And if you didn't understand the significance of how `contains` is declared: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_where_clauses

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Classes don't automatically inherit any equality logic from the base classs, so you need to be explicit and have `Foo` to conform to the `Equatable` protocol.

Actually, the only sensible equality the compiler could derive from that class declaration is the identity, and you probably don't want that.

Please note that

```
class Foo {}
```

is not the same as

```
class Foo : NSObject { }
```

By inheriting from `NSObject` you also inherit the default implementation of `isEqual`, which provides object identity equality.

---

Concerning your last update, you're only missing the `Equatable` protocol in the class definition. The following compiles just fine

```
class Foo : Equatable {}

func ==(lhs: Foo, rhs: Foo) -> Bool {
    return ObjectIdentifier(lhs) == ObjectIdentifier(rhs)
    // or simply
    // return lhs === rhs
}

let foo = Foo()
let foos = [Foo(), Foo()]

contains(foos, foo)
```

Or simply inherit from `NSObject`, which already provides identity equality

```
class Foo : NSObject {}

let foo = Foo()
let foos = [Foo(), Foo()]

contains(foos, foo)
```

Comment: Maybe he does want identity. But it's completely open-ended; he hasn't said what he thinks it means for two Foos to be "equal".

Comment: @matt if you inherit from `NSObject` you get identity by default. It wouldn't be so unreasonable to think to get the same behavior when omitting the base class.

Comment: That is why I told him (in a comment) that if he derived from NSObject things would have been different.

Comment: @matt yup, that's correct, I'm saying that it wouldn't be unreasonable to think that `NSObject` inheritance were the default, especially if coming from another language. You were spot on in pointing it out.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain this. Still learning the ropes :)

Comment: Would `func ==(lhs: Foo, rhs: Foo) -> Bool { return lys === hrs }` have the same effect?

Comment: @BrianNickel yes, it does.

Answer (score 2):

The only function signature for `contains` is:

```
func contains<S : SequenceType where S.Generator.Element : Equatable>(seq: S, x: S.Generator.Element) -> Bool
```

`Foo` is not `Equatable`, so it doesn't match this signature.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response rob. I'm still new to swift so that signature is still a little foreign looking. I finally got it figured out though :)

Answer (score 0):

Also note that there is always a way to check for an instance of a class in an array, even if you haven't implemented the equatable protocol or inherited from `NSObject`. You can use `reduce` to do it like this:

```
class MyClass { }
let myClass1 = MyClass()
let myArray = [myClass1]

let lookForMyClass1 = myArray.reduce(false) { $0 || $1 === myClass1 }

println(lookForMyClass1)  // Outputs: true
```

And you can generalize that to look for any class object in any `SequenceType` by overloading `contains` with something like this:

```
func contains<T: AnyObject, S: SequenceType where T == S.Generator.Element>(#haystack: S, #needle: T) -> Bool {
    return reduce(haystack, false) { $0 || $1 === needle }
}
```

Now you can call `contains` like this:

```
let searchForMyClass1 = contains(haystack: myArray, needle: myClass1)

println(searchForMyClass1)  // Output: true
```